# dtd error extra content at the end of the file

Tags: xml, dtd

Cant seem to fix my code. I get this error that says extra content at the end of the file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Catalog [
<!ELEMENT Catalog (Movie+)>
<!ELEMENT Movie (Title,Year,Length,TopBilledActors)>
<!ELEMENT Title (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Year (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Length (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT TopBilledActors (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST Movie movieID ID #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST Movie genre (Drama|Fantasy|Action|Comedy) #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST Movie earningsrank CDATA #IMPLIED>
]>
```

Comment: It is working fine for me. How and where are you getting error?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you write a file.dtd!
If i try to write this code into a DTD file I get this error (extra content at the end of the file):

test.dtd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Catalog [
<!ELEMENT Catalog (Movie+)>
<!ELEMENT Movie (Title,Year,Length,TopBilledActors)>
<!ELEMENT Title (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Year (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Length (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT TopBilledActors (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST Movie movieID ID #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST Movie genre (Drama|Fantasy|Action|Comedy) #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST Movie earningsrank CDATA #IMPLIED>
]>
```

But if i write a xml file it work fine (and nothing error):

test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Catalog [
<!ELEMENT Catalog (Movie+)>
<!ELEMENT Movie (Title,Year,Length,TopBilledActors)>
<!ELEMENT Title (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Year (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Length (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT TopBilledActors (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST Movie movieID ID #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST Movie genre (Drama|Fantasy|Action|Comedy) #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST Movie earningsrank CDATA #IMPLIED>
]>
<Catalog>
    <Movie movieID="a123" genre="Drama">
    <Title></Title>
    <Year></Year>
    <Length></Length>
    <TopBilledActors></TopBilledActors>
</Movie></Catalog>
```